# How do I dynamically allocate memory to a pointer array inside a structure

Tags: c, data-structures, dynamic-memory-allocation

here is what i have in done so far

```
struct test_case {
  int n;
  int *test[];
};


struct test_case *test_case_struct = (struct test_case *)malloc(
      sizeof(struct test_struct) + 100 * sizeof(int));
```

I need to allocate n pointers in the "test" pointer array. As far as i know i need to allocate space to the structure and then some more for the pointer array, but when i try to compile this, i get the error 
**invalid use of sizeof operator for to incomplete type struct test_struct**

if someone could please inform me how i can take the value of **n as a user input** and have **int *test [n]** made possible.

Comment: try using typedef when you create your structure then use the type name in your sizeof.

Comment: Side note, but consider [not casting the result of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are using flexible array(aka zero length array).
Which can be allocated as below.

```
struct test_case *test_case_struct =
   malloc(sizeof (*test_case_struct) + 100 * sizeof (int *));
```

Note missing `*` for `int` and typo `sizeof(struct test_struct)` in your code.

---

Alternatively you can use pointer to pointer as below.

```
struct test_case {
  int n;
  int **test;
};


struct test_case *test_case_struct = malloc(
      sizeof(*test_case_struct));
test_case_struct->test = malloc(100 * sizeof(int *)); // Allocates 100 pointers
```

Comment: And why flexible array is not suitable?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I just `ass*u*me*d` OP might not intended to use flexible array and accidentally declared structure like that.

Comment: @kiranBiradar The title suggests that an array of pointers in a struct is desired.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
  sizeof(struct test_struct)
```

to

```
   sizeof(struct test_case)
```

as `test_struct` is not the correct structure type.

In a better way, you can also use the already-declared variable name, like

```
struct test_case *test_case_struct = malloc(
         sizeof (*test_case_struct) + n * sizeof(int*));
```

That said, you need to allocate memory worth of `int *`s, not `int`s, for the flexible member.

Also, below is a snippet which shows the count is taken as user input

```
int main(void)
{
    int n = 0;
    puts("Enter the count of pointers");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {
        puts("Got a problem in the input");
        exit (-1);
    }
    struct test_case *test_case_struct = malloc( sizeof(struct test_case) + n * sizeof(int*));
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: my intention is to have a pointer array that can point to **n** elements. where **n** is a user input. both **n** and pointer array being inside the structure. sorry for the typo in the snippet there

Comment: @ShivaKumar So, you are saying, you don't need an array of pointers to `int`s, rather an array of `int`s, the count of the `int`s would be stored in `n`, right?

Comment: nope. if i were to have a pointer array int *test[n], n would be a user input (this alone is not challenging for me, i gave done it before), the complexity is where i need to put the pointer array **int *test[ ]** inside a structure, and also its size **int n** inside a structure. the **use case** i am needing this for is i have the user inputting different square matrices of different dimensions (**int n**). each pointer in the **test[0], test[1] ... test[n]** is pointing to an **int array** which inturn have **n** elements in it. i hope i have made the picture clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Don't repeat type names. You already stumbled over your own code twice because you did that. You made the mistake of typing the wrong struct tag and confusing `int*` for `int`.

A more hardy allocation would look like this

```
struct test_case *test_case_struct =
  malloc(sizeof (*test_case_struct) + sizeof (test_case_struct->test[0]) * 100);
```

This here will allocate the size of whatever `test_case_struct` points at, plus 100 more of whatever `test_case_struct->test[0]` should be. Now you can play with the structure definition without breaking this call to malloc. And if you do perform a breaking change (like renaming `test`), you'll be notified by your compiler promptly.